# Why user is added back in database after deletion?

Tags: plugin-development

I am creating a custom plugin, the users for the plugin are saved in a separate table and there is a table that display all users having edit and delete links. while delete link is clicked, the user got deleted but returning back to page displaying users adds the user back in database !!!!

> It is happening only with last inserted user, rest working fine, means I can delete other users successfully.

wordpress version 4.5.2

> It seems it is because register function is called with admin_init
>   hook and it is called every time user visits the admin area, but no
>   idea how it can be solved .

user deletion

```
public function _myplugin_user_edit_user_page()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = 'myplugin_users';
    if(isset($_GET['operation'])){
        if($_GET['operation'] == 'delete'){
            $wpdb->delete( $table_name, array( 'myplugin_user_id' => $_GET['id']) );
        }
    }
}
```

user registartion

```
public function _myplugin_user_registration()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = 'myplugin_users';

    if( get_option('myplugin_user_option_name') != null){
        $myplugin_user_name = get_option('myplugin_user_option_name')['myplugin_user_first_name'];
        $myplugin_user_first_name = get_option('myplugin_user_option_name')['myplugin_user_first_name'];
        $myplugin_user_last_name = get_option('myplugin_user_option_name')['myplugin_user_last_name'];
        $myplugin_user_email = get_option('myplugin_user_option_name')['myplugin_user_email'];
        $random_password = wp_hash_password( wp_generate_password( $length=12, $include_standard_special_chars=false ) ); 

        $get_user = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT myplugin_user_login FROM myplugin_users WHERE myplugin_user_email="' . $myplugin_user_email . '" LIMIT 1', ARRAY_A);
        $user_exist = array_column($get_user, 'myplugin_user_login');
        if( !in_array($myplugin_user_name, $user_exist) ){
            $wpdb->insert(
                $table_name,
                array(
                    'myplugin_user_login' => $myplugin_user_name,
                    'myplugin_user_first_name' => $myplugin_user_first_name,
                    'myplugin_user_last_name' => $myplugin_user_last_name,
                    'myplugin_user_pass' => $random_password,
                    'myplugin_user_nice_name' => $myplugin_user_name,
                    'myplugin_user_email' => $myplugin_user_email,
                    'myplugin_user_url' => null,
                    'myplugin_user_registrated' => current_time( 'mysql' ), 
                    'myplugin_user_activation_key' => null,
                    'myplugin_user_status' => 0,
                    'myplugin_display_name' => $myplugin_user_name
                )
            );
        }
    } else {
        $user_error_msg['_myplugin_existing_user_email'] = 'The user is already registered!';
    }
}
```

display users

```
    function _myplugin_user_display()
    {
        global $wpdb;
        global $wp;
        if(!$wp->did_permalink){
            $edit_url = admin_url() . 'admin.php?page=myplugin-user-edit-page';
        }
        $get_users = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT myplugin_user_id, myplugin_user_login, myplugin_user_first_name, myplugin_user_last_name, myplugin_user_email FROM myplugin_users', ARRAY_A);
        $table = '';
        $table .= '<table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped myplugin-users-table">';


        $table .=  '<thead><tr class="header-row"><td id="cb" class="manage-column column-cb check-column"><label class="screen-reader-text" for="cb-select-all-1">Select All</label><input id="cb-select-all-1" type="checkbox"></td>';


        $table .= '<th scope="col" class="manage-column header">Username</th>';
        $table .= '<th scope="col" class="manage-column header">Name</th>';
        $table .= '<th scope="col" class="manage-column header">Email</th>';

        $table .= '</tr></thead><tbody>';
        foreach( $get_users as  $key=>$user){
            $table .= '<tr class="content-row"><th scope="row" class="check-column"><label class="screen-reader-text" for="cb-select-">Select Nunc eget ultricies libero</label>
                <input id="cb-select-'. $key .'" class="select-post" type="checkbox" name="post[]" value="'.$key .'">
                <div class="locked-indicator"></div>
             </th>';

            $table = $table  .= '<td class="has-row-actions column-primary report" id="">'
                                     . '<strong><span class="post">' . $user['myplugin_user_login'] . '</a></span></strong>'
                                     .'<a href="'. $edit_url . '&operation=edit&id=' . $user["myplugin_user_id"] . '"> Edit</a>'
                                     .'<a href="'. $edit_url . '&operation=delete&id=' . $user["myplugin_user_id"] . '"> Delete</a>'
                                    . '</td>';
            $table = $table  .= '<td class="has-row-actions column-primary report" id="">'
                                     . '<strong><span class="post">' . $user['myplugin_user_first_name'] . " " . $user['myplugin_user_last_name'] . '</a></span></strong>'
                                    . '</td>';

            $table = $table  .= '<td class="has-row-actions column-primary report" id="">'
                                     . '<strong><span class="post">' . $user['myplugin_user_email'] . '</a></span></strong>'
                                    . '</td>';
        }
        $table .= '</tbody></table>';   

        echo  "page link " . $edit_url;
        echo $table;
    }
}
```

may be related to ([Why does “get_option” pull in the older value in options.php, rather than the newer value, on submission of a form?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/159807/why-does-get-option-pull-in-the-older-value-in-options-php-rather-than-the-ne))

but can not solve my problem.

Comment: Where's the code that displays the users? You said `but returning back to page displaying users adds the user back in database`. And what's up with the options? Are you storing same data both in your own table and options table?! WordPress uses options table with every request - it has to be as light as possible.

Comment: @N00b edited my code, please check it now.

Comment: I'm going to jump the gun and say the user isn't actually _re-added_ -  if you   were to re-load the page the user would then be gone, yes? If so, it's because you pull the users table into memory to later display them, but _before_ you run the delete query.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic what happens is first  when I click the delete link, it deletes the user from database, then I have not written any code to redirect you can notice it, now when I come back, and reload the database, I am getting the user back .

Comment: @N00b please look at the code I have posted in gist, the comment before this contains the link.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic please give some idea about it, what can be done or something like ......

Comment: Pretty sure it's because your delete function isn't actually working - either it's not firing at all (when you think it is), or there is a syntax error in your PHP/SQL. Make sure you have [debugging enabled](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). I can't really continue to help as this is a very localised issue, and I simply don't have the time to offer this level of support.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic the delete function is working, after delete, i reloaded the database and the last user is not there, but when I reload the wordpress page, the user is present and now reloading the database too.yes my debugging is enabled .

Comment: The delete function _isn't_ working if the user is still there...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39552/discussion-between-prafulla-kumar-sahu-and-thedeadmedic).

Comment: @TheDeadMedic I think there is something related to session or something may be the last inserted user data is remaining and posted again on page reload, is there any chance of something like this ??
if the delete function is not working, how I am getting it disappeared from database ? that is why I believe the delete function is working, but may be the _xarbo_user_registration() function is running again when page is reloading, but no idea how it is happening and how it can be stopped ?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic yes, when the user is added again the xarbo_user_id is changing .

Comment: @TheDeadMedic It seems to be because of admin_init hook, as the registration function is hooked to it and it will be executed every time the user visits the admin area . Can you please share your view on it ?

Comment: Ah I see - yes, your registration code runs on `admin_init` and will automatically insert the user if they do not already exist. You need to change your logic/add a flag elsewhere (i.e. usermeta) to indicate that the user has been deleted and not to re-add it.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic  I am not using wordpress table, so there is no user meta table now :( is there any other way ??

Comment: I really can't advise any further - I have very little understanding about your project and this is very quickly verging into a free private consultation.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic I used ajax and a custom hook to get it working, but now trying to find out if there is any other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by doing something link

```
$hook = add_menu_page('My Plugin Settings','My Plugin Settings','manage_options','my_plugin_settings','display_plugin_options');
add_action('load-'.$hook,'do_on_my_plugin_settings_save');

function do_on_my_plugin_settings_save()
{
  if(isset($_GET['settings-updated']) && $_GET['settings-updated'])
   {
      //plugin settings have been saved. Here goes your code
   }
}
```